# Using managed plugin and unmanaged plugin for Unity3D android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dll, plugins, unmanaged

I am developing a managed `dll` that's a wrapper and refers to a native `dll` (compiled in a Windows OS). The idea is that Unity developers will be able to use the managed `dll` for purposes of developing AR applications on Android devices.

So far I am successfully able to call managed `dll` functions from android device but it throws error when it tries to call functions from the unmanaged `dll`. Here I am assuming is that Android is unable to access native unmanaged plugins.

I have been researching quite a lot on this topic but I am not able to get a proper head around it and I don't have much experience in Android development.

What would be the best way to go about this scenario? Should I compile the native plugin to a `.so` library? Is it possible to refer to this from the managed `dll`?

Any help here would be appreciated!